# setup with rate n not rate and divide by date

Tags: vb.net

I have a system where every invoice will include 6% gst (before June). Starting from now, every invoice needs to have a gst rate of 0%.

But after I change rate to 0%, old invoices which should be 6%, will be set to 0%.
What I want is to change gst 0% for all new records, effective from the end of June. But not to effect previous invoices.

How to make a date to solve it

0% only for a new invoice start from 1 June
6% for old invoices before June

I have the code this code setting tax rate to 0.

```
If gst_total > 0 then 
tax_rate = 0
```

Total invoice will multiple with 0% include old invoice(before this 6%)

```
If gst_total > 0 Then
tax_rate = 6
Else
tax_rate = 0
End If
```

Any ideas? I need help

Comment: its unclear what you're asking

Comment: my mean is have a two invoice holds 6% n 0%.. 6% for old invoice n 0% for new invoice.. the problem is when i set up 0% for new invoice it will effected to old invoice..6% old invoice become 0%.. i want to maintain 6% for old invoice n 0% just for a new invoice

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using a date value in your gst_total. Are you asking where to put one? Can you share more information about your model? Does it have a `created_at` date?

Comment: have a created date in database..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If InvoiceDate < New DateTime(2018, 6, 1) Then
    TaxRate = 6
Else
    TaxRate = 0
End If
```

From Microsoft Docs...

```
Dim MyString As String = "Jan 1, 2009"
Dim MyDateTime As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(MyString)
```

For different cultures...

```
Dim MyCultureInfo As CultureInfo = New CultureInfo("de-DE")
Dim MyString As String = "12 Juni 2008"
Dim MyDateTime As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(MyString, MyCultureInfo)
```

Comment: i got it..thanks Mary...
how to call from it to display in label
example "lb_tax_rate.Text = "GST @ " & tax_rate & "%"

Comment: get a error when want preview at this line Dim InvoiceDate As Date = ""
'Conversion from string "" to type 'Date' is not valid.'

Comment: See my edits to my answer. More details available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/parsing-datetime